# dynamically added HTML elements won't be affected by plugins !

Tags: javascript, jquery

there are plugins such as [flowplayer overlay](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay.html) that asks to put a "rel" attribute to the HTML element to make it trigger certain events ... the problem is , when I create dynamically elements that have that rel attribute ,, they won't trigger it ... what is the solution for this !?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the **[`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** method to trigger events for dynamically created elements.

**Example:**

```
$('selector').live('click', function(){
  // your code .........................
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since jQuery 1.4.2 you can also use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

> **Description:** Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.

The use of delegate can sometimes result in less and more understandable code than `.live()`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the plugin so it uses `live()` to handle events.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there is the jQuery [**live()**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to address exactly this kind of issue.

You would have to change the plugin to use `live()`, or run their initialization function every time new content is added.

The latter approach can be pretty resource-intensive on the client end and is not very clean, but if the number of elements in question is not too much, it can often be the easiest way.